# Blazored Fluent Validation Against Collection Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, validation, blazor, fluentvalidation

When I build an edit form against a single class, everything works as expected. The red/green indicators show up when I leave the field. However, when I make that a collection, I lose the red/green logic when I leave the field. It now always turns green when indeed the validation should fail. When I manually call

```cs
_fluentValidationValidator.Validate(opt => opt.IncludeAllRuleSets())
```

it validates and changes the field outline accordingly.

How do I have the validation run appropriately when I leave the field when dealing with a collection?

```html
<EditForm Model="Form">
    <FluentValidationValidator @ref="_fluentValidationValidator" />
    
    @foreach (var item in Form.Items)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6 col-md-3 mb-1">
                <label class="input-label">Name</label>
                <InputText @bind-Value="item.Name"
                                Style="width:100%;" />

                <ValidationMessage For="() => item.Name" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</EditForm>
```

```cs
public class TestForm
{
    public List<TestItem> Items { get; set; } = new();
}
```

```cs
public class TestFormValidator : AbstractValidator<TestForm>
{
    public TestFormValidator()
    {
        RuleForEach(r => r.Items).SetValidator(new TestItemValidator());
    }
}
```

```cs
public class TestItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class TestItemValidator : AbstractValidator<TestItem>
{
    public TestItemValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Name)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Name is required")
            .MaximumLength(6).WithMessage("Name should be at most 6 characters");
    }
}
```

Comment: Currently facing the same issue, would be nice to have some documentation around this, or even if there is documentation, would be nice to have it easier to find and to learn from.

Just so I'm providing more information, I have the validators working in unit testing, but can not get the messages to appear in the UI.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm stuck with the same thing

Comment: Unfortunately not. I ended up bailing on it after trying to get it working for days.

Answer (score 0):

It works if you use validator via DI and not create any local implementation or instance.

```cs
public class TravelersDto
{
    public List<TravelerDto> Travelers { get; set; } = new();
}

public class TravelersDtoValidator : AbstractValidator<TravelersDto>
{
    public TravelersDtoValidator()
    {
        RuleForEach(x => x.Travelers).SetValidator(new TravelerDtoValidator());
    }
}
```

than use it in your form as:

```cs
@code {
private TravelersDto viewModel = new();
}
```

and

```html
  <EditForm Model="viewModel" OnValidSubmit="Save">  
    <FluentValidationValidator></FluentValidationValidator>
    <ValidationSummary></ValidationSummary>
```